# problem with my my theme "search.php"

Tags: themes

**when I try to search something it shows me that I have an error in line 9**

> The code on line 9 on my page "search.php" of my theme

```
<div class="p-title"><h2 style="background-color: #1AB3EE;">Searching for <?php $allsearch = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); $key = wp_specialchars($s, 1); $count = $allsearch->post_count; _e(''); _e('<strong class="terms_search">'); echo $key; _e('</strong>'); _e(' - About '); echo $count . ' '; _e('results'); wp_reset_query(); ?></h2></div>
```

> The error message

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `&new` in object creation is deprecated in PHP 7+ because objects are passed by be reference by default.  Remove the `&`

Comment: thank you so much! that solved my problem :)